# Exception while submitting a form in WFFM - HideInner is set to false

Tags: wffm

I have the issue with submitting a WFFM form on CD instance hosted in Azure. The message shown after submit is

> "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
>   (Exception.HideInner is set to false)...

and I don't see any error in the logs (application insights). If I submit the same form in CM server - all goes well. Any ideas?

Btw, I set `WFM.MasterDatabase` setting to web in  `Sitecore.Forms.Xtune.CD.config` and `Sitecore.Forms.config` for the CD server...but the same issue

The Web Forms for Marketers version: 8.2 rev. 170413

Comment: Do you have custom actions for the form? or are you just using Send email action?

Comment: the form has no custom actions and no validation...it has no fields just a submit button

Comment: Did you upgrade WFFM recently or it is a fresh install?

Answer (score -1):

this was the issue and the fix: http://sitecorexdb.blogspot.com.by/2017/02/InvalidCastException.html

Thanks all for help!

Comment: Please edit your post to include the actual solution. We don't consider [**link-only answers**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/) as good content.